# What are the alternatives of UNLAYER generated preview images?

Tags: image, templates, frontend, backend, libraries

Currently, I'm using Unlayer for generating the preview images but the output given by it is very inconsistent. That's why I need to get the control over everything using the **JSON only** (JSON can consists of images, links, headings, etc.). If something is required on Backend side, I can use Spring Boot using Java, but if there is anything else more suitable then that is also fine. On the frontend side, you can use anything. You can use any library or 3rd parties to achieve the desired results.

I'm unable to find any other library which can serves the purpose.